# Updating database field in PHP when link is pressed

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

My page lists out all of the rows from a MySQL table and puts them inside separate divs as links.

```
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<a href='projects/" . $row['dir'] . "'><div>";
            echo "<h2>" . $row['name'] . "</h2>";
            echo "<p>Created: " . $row['date_created'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p>Last opened: " . $row['date_last_opened'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p>" . $row['description'] . "</p>";
            echo "</div></a>";
        }
```

When I click on a box (div), it opens that specific project. What I need, is to update the 'date_last_opened' field for a project to the current date when I click into one. The column for it in the table is of type 'date'.

Thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: Somekind of redirect to project with update row.

Comment: Does the value of `date_last_opened` change in your database prior to opening the project in which it's found?

Comment: can you use javascript and Jquery or you want to do  only with PHP?

Comment: @noob I don't mind using JavaScript and Jquery if there is an easy work around with them. Not too great with it though.

Comment: @che-azeh No the value does not change. I manually put them into the table, so it's static at the moment. I just need it to update to the current date when the link is pressed.

Comment: [Try Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)

Comment: @che-azeh The only area that I think, that will require our attention, and then I have I suggested the static classes. It is in the area of ... In the area ... I would say so, as a kind of analogy with what happens in console log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple method would be use of Jquery and AJAX:

First add click function to your link in while loop like this:

```
echo "<a href='projects/" . $row['dir'] . "' onclick='update(".$row['name'].")';><div>";
```

and in your JS file use Jquery Ajax:

```
function update(name){
var now = new Date();
var dateToInsert = now.format("dd/M/yy h:mm tt");//or whatever format you need
var projectName = name;

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "update.php",
data: { date: dateToInsert, name: projectName}
})
.done(function( msg ) {
alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
}
```

and your update.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['date']) && $_POST['name']){
$sql = "update yourTable set date ='".$_POST['date']."' where name= '".$_POST['name']."'";
//Rest of the code to execute query
}
else{
    echo "AJAX call failed to send post variables";
}
```

Comment: This worked great. I had an ID column in the table, so I used that instead of the 'name'. And in the SQL query, I had to format it like so: 

...SET date_last_opened = '".$_POST['date']."' WHERE...

And for anyone else, the date.format works using [this.](https://gist.github.com/eralston/968809) Many thanks again.